# What is the proper isolation level needed in this postgres query with concurrent transaction?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 concurrent transactions

on table X with the following column

```
id
count
```

and

table Y with the following column

```
id
somefield
```

currently there is only 1 row in tableX

```
id=1
count=0
```

and a million row in tableY

transaction 1

```
Begin
     select * where id = 1 from tableX
     select count(*) from tableY
     update set count = count + 1 from tableX
END
```

transaction 2

```
Begin
     select * where id = 1 from tableX
     select count(*) from tableY
     update set count = count + 1 from tableX
END
```

If isolation level is REPEATABLE READ , postgres will snapshot id=1

and the result of both transaction will be count=1 instead of count=2

Should i use SERIALIZABLE isolation to lock the row instead? But if I use SERIALIZABLE isolation it locks the entire tableY will millions of row

is there more fine grain lock available in postgres?

Answer (score 1):

you should lock the row, from the start in every transaction, when you want to keep all updates, even when there are parallel.

```
Begin
     select * where id = 1 from tableX FOR NO KEY UPDATE;
     select count(*) from tableY;
     update set count = count + 1 from tableX;
END
```

Forisolation levels you shouldalways consult the [namual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE)

Comment: Should be `FOR NO KEY UPDATE`.